# Is it better to convert jade to html or just use jade when using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Now with grunt plugins I can convert jade to pure html easily.
What is the best practice when deploying html to node server.
Is it better to leave jade as it is or convert into html then deploy it?
Does it improve time when node is starting up and other others?

Comment: Define 'better' for your specific case. Each approach has its pros and cons.

Comment: starting node up faster, browsing through different pages (static & dyanamic) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option: to render on the client.

But your question is too general, it depends!

### render jade on server side (JADE -> HTML)

pro: can use placeholder
contra: need node.js, express on the server

### render jade on the client (JADE -> JS)

pro: no node.js on the server - just a static http service
contra: need jade runtime on the client

### convert at compile time (HTML at runtime)

pro: fast, no runtime rendering engine needed
contra: only dynamic until compile time, not dynamic at runtime

---

> Does it improve time when node is starting up and other others?

I think you can ignore the starup time for node.js and requiring express. But you can measure the time for each request express and jade will need and compare it with a static file serving service like apache, nginx. For both solutions you can using caching techniques.